# Sequelize - Custom Create Method

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Is it possible to create a custom `create` method in `Sequelize`. I would like it so that I could pass in a URL to download a thumbnail photo from, and then a method would be called with that data to download the photo, upload it to S3, and save that S3 URL as the thumbnailPhotoURL.

Here is an example of the syntax I'm trying to do:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE,
  thumbnailPhotoURL: Sequelize.STRING
});

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  return User.create({
    username: 'janedoe',
    birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20),
    // this will be used to download and upload the thumbnailPhoto to S3
    urlToDownloadThumbnailPhotoFrom: 'http://example.com/test.png'
  });
}).then(function(jane) {
  console.log(jane.get({
    plain: true
  }));
});
```

Notice how I'm calling `User.create` with a `urlToDownloadThumbnailPhotoFrom` parameter, rather than a `thumbnailPhotoURL` parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use before create hook no need to define a custom create function

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE,
  thumbnailPhotoURL: Sequelize.STRING
});


User.beforeCreate(function(model, options, cb) { 
   var urlToDownloadThumbnailPhotoFrom = model.urlToDownloadThumbnailPhotoFrom;


//.....Here you write the logic to get s3 url using urlToDownloadThumbnailPhotoFrom and then assign it to model and call the call back it will automatically get saved

  model.thumbnailPhotoURL = thumbnailPhotoURL;
  cb();
});
```